# Convert 2 JSON objects into single javascript array Angularjs

Tags: javascript

Here is what I try to convert:

```
[{"id":4,"name":"Group4"},{"id":6,"name":"Group6"}]
```

So I want to convert it into single JavaScript array like:

```
[4,6]
```

Comment: may be: 
`arr = arr.map(function(el){ return el.id; });`

Comment: Are you asking if there is a built in angular way to do this? Or are you looking for a JavaScript solution?

Answer (score 3):

Use `map`: `inputArray.map(function (element) { return element.id; });`